# Postgresql: write user function with coalesce-like behaviour

Tags: postgresql, null, coalesce

I want to write a function, which counts not-null values of input. My solution is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
  count_not_null (VARIADIC args anyarray) RETURNS BIGINT
  AS $$
    SELECT COUNT(x) FROM unnest(args) as x
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
;
```

This function works like a charm while input contains at least one not-null value. But if input contains only null values (like `SELECT count_not_null(null, null)`) the error

> "*ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type
>   "unknown"*"

thrown. But if we look to `COALESCE`, it handles this case: just returns `null`. How can I get some behaviour for user-defined function?

Comment: You probably don't want to (or can't) cast the parameters I guess? `select count_not_null(null::bigint, null::bigint)`

Comment: `SELECT count_not_null(null::int, null::int)`,possible ?

Comment: Of course I can cast parameters, but I want to achieve behaviour of `COALESCE` function.

Comment: You may be able to work around it by providing a version with a concrete type too. I'm not sure if that'll cause type resolution problems for that type, but I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

Building on Craig Ringer's comment, the following works on PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
  count_not_null (VARIADIC args anyarray) RETURNS BIGINT
  AS $$
    SELECT COUNT(x) FROM unnest(args) as x
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
;

-- Overloading with a version that expects a TEXT array
CREATE FUNCTION
  count_not_null (VARIADIC args TEXT[]) RETURNS BIGINT
  AS $$
    SELECT COUNT(x) FROM unnest(args) as x
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
;
```